# How to add click event to an img element in jquery grid

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery grid and i have added img element to a grid column value with the formatter. How di i add click event to that element and hide /show the image based on a condition.

```
{
  name : 'adjust',
  formatter : function (){
    return "<img src='xxx'>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest and to me the best way is to give the image a class, `return "<img class='my_img' src='xxx'>";`

Then using jquery you use the code below:

```
$ (document).on ('click', '.my_img', function (e) {
    var obj = $ (this);

    if (obj.hasClass ('hide'))
        obj.removeClass ('hide'); // or add a placeholder, etc
    else
        obj.addClass ('hide');
});
```

`$ (document).on ('click', '.my_img', function (e).... is used beacuse if any image is added after the page has load, the click event will still work on those new ones

`var obj = $ (this);` is used because depending on what you do in the function, `this` could be different.

By using the above coe, when your image hides you will not be able to click on it again :) this is just an example of how to add the click event

Comment: But to change the image you can also just change the source to a place holder instead of hiding the image by using `obj.attr ('src','path_to_new_image');`